# CoreLocation requestWhenInUseAuthorization() not working in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, core-location

I want my app to show the user's location but it doesn't ask for WhenInUseAuthorization. I added the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in the Info.plist. I tried in the iOS simulator with simulate location & on an actual device.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    var locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .NotDetermined {
            self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {

        if CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() == .AuthorizedWhenInUse {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            mapView.showsUserLocation = true

            let userLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude, locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude)
            mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation, 100, 100)

        } else {

            let defaultLocation = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(45.5017, -73.5673)
            mapView.region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(defaultLocation, 100, 100)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This was my mistake, I added the NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in the test folder's Info.plist instead of the main project's plist.

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed user location on simulator? If you didn't change it, you can't get the "user location".

Comment: I did change it and it didn't work. And I also tried on my iphone 6 and it didn't get my user location.

Comment: is `startUpdatingLocation()` being called?

Comment: I don't think so, I added a print statement just after startUpdatingLocation() & there was no console output. Also I just realised that simulate location in xCode and the custom location in the iOS simulator turn themselves off when I click on the build button.

Comment: add console debug at delegate func: `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!)`. It needs to be called once at least.

Comment: It is called with status = (CLAuthorizationStatus) NotDetermined.

Comment: `.NotDetermined` means user has not made its choice but I have seen sources which claim that it can occur when location services being enabled for the app but not turned on the device. Are you sure location services are enabled under `Setting->Privacy->location services` on device?

Comment: Location services are enabled on my iphone 6.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you call requestWhenInUseAuthorization too early. Try to call in `didChangeAuthorizationStatus` delegate.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    if status == CLAuthorizationStatus.NotDetermined {
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
}
```